# Reorder within a group

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table containing data about how each group solves problems:

```
PROB | GROUP   | REPNO | STATUS
-----+---------+-------+-------
 1   | Juniors |    0  |
 1   | Seniors |    1  |
 1   | Juniors |    2  |
 1   | Experts |    3  | SOLVED
 2   | Juniors |    0  |
 2   | Seniors |    1  | SOLVED
```

Column PROB defines problems that groups were solving, column GROUP defines which group was working on this prob, column REPNO defines the number of solving repetition (repeated tries until it was finally solved, 0 means first try, no repetition yet), and final column STATUS defines whether task was solved in that particular try. Here I can make distribution how work was efficiently solved in each repetition by ALL GROUPS (SELECT ... GROUP BY repno).

But I want to show how efficiently probs were solvved  by each particular group (distribution per group's own repetition order). For example, PROB 1 was tried 2 times by group Juniors, and once by group Seniors and was not solved, and finally solved by group Experts in their first try.

So I need to make recalculation of repetition for each particular group:

```
PROB | GROUP   | REPNO | REPNO_J | REPNO_S | REPNO_E | STATUS
-----+---------+-------+---------+---------+---------+-------
 1   | Juniors |    0  |       0 |         |         |
 1   | Seniors |    1  |         |       0 |         |         
 1   | Juniors |    2  |       1 |         |         |        
 1   | Experts |    3  |         |         |       0 | SOLVED  <-- experts solved in first try
 2   | Juniors |    0  |       0 |         |         |
 2   | Seniors |    1  |         |       0 |         | SOLVED  <-- seniors solved in first try
```

How to make this recalculation?

Comment: Is it fixed that you have **3 groups** or will the group number vary from case to case?

Comment: The number of groups will not vary.

Comment: Are any of the posted answers acceptable for you or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: Sorry for taking reserved word GROUP for column name in my example. Silly of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE RANK() <kbd>[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/633a1/8/0)</kbd>

```
select 
  PROB, 
  GROUP1, 
  REPNO,
  DECODE(GROUP1,'Juniors', rank() over (partition by prob, group1 order by repno) - 1) as REPNO_J,
  DECODE(GROUP1,'Seniors', rank() over (partition by prob, group1 order by repno) - 1) as REPNO_S,
  DECODE(GROUP1,'Experts', rank() over (partition by prob, group1 order by repno) - 1) as REPNO_E,
  STATUS
from mytable
order by prob,repno
```

Comment: Thanks @Jaugar Chang, that's very elegant solution. Even more, you offered an example in SQLfiddle, you're the one.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ROW_NUMBER windowing function to get the number per group:

```
select 
  prob, 
  "GROUP", 
  repno,
  case when "GROUP" = 'Juniors' then try end as repno_j,
  case when "GROUP" = 'Seniors' then try end as repno_s,
  case when "GROUP" = 'Experts' then try end as repno_e,
  status
from
(
   select 
     prob, "GROUP", repno, status,
     row_number() over(partition by prob, "GROUP" order by repno) - 1 as try
   from mytable
)
order by prob, repno;
```

By the way: It is not a good idea to Name a column GROUP. This is a reserved word in SQL. So you must use quotes with it and consider upper/lower case whenever you use the name in a query.

Comment: Much better solution. `ANALYTIC` takes care of the order within each group as mentioned in the `PARTITION` BY clause.

Comment: This solution works fine. @Lalit Kumar B, you already gave here three comments recommending ANALYTIC, please give us your solution not just comments. We'd like to see it.

Comment: @sbrbot, >`We'd like to see it` Who all are you referring to by saying **WE**? You have asked the question, and people have responded. What I had to say, was technically answered. So, I just commented on this answer with my opinion about why analytic is better. I hope you got your answer and my opinion would have helped you to **understand** why it is a better solution. And where did you see three comments? Really surprising to see the tone of speech of **you** as the asker.

Answer (score 0):

you can use CASE Statement

```
SELECT "PROB", 
       "GROUP",
       "REPNO",
       (CASE WHEN  "GROUP" = 'Juniors' THEN REPNO ELSE NULL END ) as REPNO_J,
       (CASE WHEN  "GROUP" = 'Seniors' THEN REPNO ELSE NULL END ) as REPNO_S,
       (CASE WHEN  "GROUP" = 'Experts' THEN REPNO ELSE NULL END ) as REPNO_E
FROM Table1
```

Comment: `CASE` is not feasible when there are too many conditions to be checked. Better use `ANALYTIC` function which takes care of the order within each `group` as mentioned in the `PARTITION BY ` clause.

Comment: @LalitKumarB, can you elaborate or give solution using ANALYTIC function

Comment: Look at Thorsten's answer. In addition, how many `CASE` conditions would you write?

Comment: @LalitKumarB, i see case conditions in Thorsten's answer also

Comment: No, this is not that. This solution does not make reorder, it just extracts existing order number for each particular group. Unfortunately, that's not what was asked. However, thanks for try.